# Is it possible to create an app bundle with price tier 0 (Free)?

Tags: ios, app-store, bundle, app-store-connect

I'm thinking on make an app Bundle on App Store with Apps which are free. It's possible to create a free app bundle on App Store?

As far I can see, minimum price option is Tier 1 (not Tier 0) and Apple talks about 'reduced price pack', so it seems to be no option to group several free apps in a free Apple Bundle.

Thanks,

Comment: If they're already free, what's the point of a bundle?

Comment: It is not possible to give away app bundles for free. See [Apple's description of what an app bundle is and the conditions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/) (one condition is "App bundles must offer a discount compared to the separate purchase price of the individual bundled apps").

Comment: Thanks to both. The point is to group applications by content, so users cant download several at a time and not to search one by one.

Comment: Also this wouldn't be a bad strategy for using a more popular app for marketing to show users a new one.

Answer (score 5):

No. See: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BundlingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH37-SW1)

> App bundles offer an easy way for your customers to purchase up to 10
>   of your paid iOS apps at a reduced price. Customers who previously
>   purchased one or more apps in an app bundle can use the Complete My
>   Bundle feature and will see the bundle price adjusted to account for
>   those previous purchases.

Comment: That's too bad. A free bundle would give the developer a slightly bigger face on the AppStore. For new users who find the bundle, they can get all of the apps at once. I have two free apps that were originally supposed to be the same app. They work together and it would be great to be able to give them away together.

Answer (score 0):

As for the other answers/comments, Tier-0 bundles are not possible at the moment.

Despite this, you still can go ahead and create a bundle of free apps: 
this will be created, can even go through the review and be approved, but it won't be made available to the store because "you must choose a compatible price" (and you can't ask for $1, a.k.a. tier-1, for a bundle of free apps).

I've created a [radar](http://www.openradar.me/37650790) on the matter: if you also agree that free bundles should exist, please feel free [to dupe it](http://www.openradar.me/37650790) at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).